# get only checked check box values

Tags: php, checkbox

It may be a simple issue but it troubles me.

When I pass a there are some checkboxes and I should get only the checked values as post value after submitting, but for now I´m getting all the values whether checked or not.

This is my code

```
<li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="contact" id="contact" value="Fill out a contact form">
    <p>Fill out a contact form </p>
</li>
<li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="quote" id="quote" value="Fill out a quote form">
    <p>Fill out a quote form </p>
</li>
<li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="signup" id="signup" value="Sign up for your mailing list">
    <p>Sign up for your mailing list </p>
</li>
<li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="search" id="search" value="Search for information">
    <p>Search for information </p>
</li>
```

And I get the value as post with its name ,I should get only the checked values wat to do

I am passing the values through ajax, so isset doesnt seems to work

Comment: Sorry, but I think you could have found the answer easily with google :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (isset($_POST['contact'])) {
//THIS CHECK BOX SELECTED
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you will have only checked checkboxes values after submitting the form in post data.

So you need to check every check box if it is set or not. if it is set then you can get this value.

try like this:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['your_checkbox_name1']){
  $Chk1 = $_REQUEST['your_checkbox_name1'];
} 

if(isset($_REQUEST['your_checkbox_name2']){
  $Chk1 = $_REQUEST['your_checkbox_name2'];
}
and so on for every checkbox ...
```